# What baud rate should I set when using screen tty for bluetooth?

Tags: gnu-screen, tty, embedded, bluetooth

I'm paired up with an Xbox Controller and want to see the output coming from the xbox controller in order to figure out its protocol.

I'm trying to do screen tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port 9600 on my mac, but I'm not sure about my baud rate. How can I determine this? It's just giving me a "Cannot open line" error.

Also, is screen tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port the right way of connecting serially to a bluetooth device? How does cat -v differ, which I got from another tutorial?

Comment: *The "cannot open line" error suggests that it isn't a baud rate problem.* My (long ago) experience with wrong baud is it connects, but everything is garbled. I used `cu` at the time, might not find that on a Mac, I believe it's packaged with uucp on Linux. `cat -v` will just show things, `cat` is one way, the `-v` makes control characters visible.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol But can screen be replaced by solely using cat and echo in conjunction with each other?

Comment: That really depends on the device. In this case, it's a Mac specific device so I have neither experience nor the computer to test with. Everything in /dev/ is special.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol But cat and echo would work on linux too, right? I don't understand why screen is necessary if those two are sufficient

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol I guess i really don't understand what screen does regarding tty

Comment: It causes `screen` to connect to serial device and use serial device protocols. Read the manpage for a hint of what that means, it's in section 6.6 "Window Types": https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Window-Types